# How to detect errors in an oozie workflow before actually running it?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am new to big data and was wondering if there is a way to detect errors in an oozie workflow before running it? Something like a compilation error sort of. Please help.
Thanks,
Annie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oozie typically runs multiple scripts, in sequence, with defined start and stops.

I think if you go through the worflow, one script at a time, that is really the only way to do a complete run before you schedule it.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use MiniOozie to run unit tests on the workflow. See [Documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/ENG_MiniOozie.html). You can run the workflow as a unit test. There are some [examples](https://github.com/apache/oozie/tree/master/minitest/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/test) too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will have a look at these.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the workflow.xml using the command line tool as below.

It performs an XML Schema validation on the specified workflow XML file.

```
oozie validate /path-to-workflow/workflow.xml
oozie validate -oozie http://<oozie-host>:11000/oozie /path-to-workflow/workflow.xml
```